# Set Css based off URL in PHP Wordpress

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I am using a website with a structure of www.example.com/blog

I have wordpress installed on the blog folder. I have a featured image that I want to have displayed on the www.example.com/blog but not on the actual blog post www.example.com/blog/post. They both use the same Css and I was wondering if I can do a conditional statement to set the display to none on the post page. I do not have access for the next 4 weeks to FTP in and change the actual code so I need a solution or advice.

I am not sure if I can use a variation of baseurl, as I am not sure how far it will back me out.

Google search didnt help me out too much

Comment: `<?php if($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == 'www.example.com/blog/post'){?> link of some other css <?php }else{?> link of other css <?php } ?>`  in your `header.php` file

Comment: Plese check and let me know worked or not?

Comment: www.example.com/blog/post what would I need to change to make this work with all posts that are titled differently, same structure